# How to initialize carousel full-width and indicators with vanilla java-script in materialize?

Tags: materialize

I am trying to enable indicators and full-width on carousel slider with vanilla Javascript in materialize but miserably failed.

I have tried it with jquery and it worked.

Here is my js vanilla script:

```
<script>
    M.AutoInit();
    var instance = M.Carousel.init({fullWidth: true, indicators: true});
</script>
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Use `M.Carousel.init()` that'll help you

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke no it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

### Explanation

As from the [docs](https://materializecss.com/carousel.html) in the `.init()` method you have to pass as first parameter the element you'd like to init. This is why your code didn't work. Materialize simply didn't know **what element** you wanted to initialize :)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    M.AutoInit();
    var options = {
        fullWidth: true, 
        indicators: true
    };
    var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
    var instance = M.Carousel.init(elem, options);
});
```

Btw, since you're using the `.AutoInit()` method at the same time, you should exclude the manually initialized element from the AutoInit...

*From the [Docs](https://materializecss.com/auto-init.html#options):*

> **Ignoring Elements**
>
> If you want `M.AutoInit()` to ignore a certain element, you can add the class `.no-autoinit` to the element and it will not be initialized by autoinit.

---

### Final code

Here is the code you should use as reference for your purpose. For the sake of completeness i've added 2 other modules from MaterializeCss (**Autocomplete** and **Dropdown**) which are initialized with the `.AutoInit()`. You can see that only the **Carousel** is not Auto-Initialized thanks to the `.no-autoinit` class

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  M.AutoInit();

  var options = {
    fullWidth: true,
    indicators: true
  };
  var elems = document.querySelector('.carousel.no-autoinit');
  console.log(elems)
  var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
})
```

```html
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
        <label for="autocomplete-input">This is auto-initialized!</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>This is auto-initialized too!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="carousel carousel-slider no-autoinit">
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/1"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/2"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/3"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/4"></a>
</div>
```